# How to get the length of a list in a list if it's randomly chosen?

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python and I wanted to generate random passwords. For this I created three lists with the possible letters, numbers and special characters. I added those lists to another list called 'all_chars'.

Now I would like to pick a random letter, number or special character in 'all_chars'. For this I generate a random number which I use as an index to get either the list of letters, numbers or special characters out of 'all_chars'. But from this time on I don't know which list is picked and therefore I don't know how to get the length of the specific list to pick a random item. Do you have any idea how to solve this in the same line of code? Or do I have to store the index of the chosen list so I can get the length of it?

The line of code where I would like to do this is the following (see ???):

`while len(password) != 16:
    password += all_chars[random.randint(0, len(all_chars))][random.randint(0, ???)]`

Complete code below:

```
import string
import random

letters = list(string.ascii_letters)
numbers = [x for x in range(0, 10)]
special_chars = ['+', '-', '!', '&', '=', ':', '.', ',', ';', '?', '@', '#', '%']
all_chars = [letters, numbers, special_chars]
password = ""

while len(password) != 16:
    password += all_chars[random.randint(0, len(all_chars))][random.randint(0, ???)] 

print(password)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend the use of random for password generation. It's insecure. Instead, try using Secrets, found here-

https://pynative.com/python-secrets-module/

---

if you were to use the more recommended module, you can generate it like so-

```
unit_list = ['+', '-', '!', '&', '=', ':', '.', ',', ';', '?', '@', '#', '%']
secure_choice = secretsGenerator.choice(unit_list)
print ("Secure random choice using secrets is ", secure_choice)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Actually it's only for an exercise but nevertheless it's good to know how to do it right once it's really needed.

Comment: that's great! glad I could help in any way!

Answer (score 1):

You may hold it in a variable, to get its length :

```
while len(password) != 16:
    chars_selection = all_chars[random.randint(0, len(all_chars))]
    password += chars_selection[random.randint(0, len(chars_selection))]
```

---

This will give you different probability, but you could put all chars in one unique list

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits

letters = list(ascii_letters)
numbers = list(digits)
special_chars = list('+-!&=:.,;?@#%')
all_chars = [*letters, *numbers, *special_chars]

while len(password) != 16:
    password += all_chars[random.randint(0, len(all_chars))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the index, you can ask random to give you a [**`choice`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) from a sequence:

```
password += choice(choice(all_chars))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that the **`random`** module is not intended to be used for password generation.  Instead you should use the **[`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html)** module:

```
import secrets
import string


special_chars = ['+', '-', '!', '&', '=', ':', '.', ',', ';', '?', '@', '#', '%']
all_chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + special_chars

def gen_password(password_length=16):
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(all_chars) for i in range(password_length))
```